# google map is not showing properly as box height is calculated on base of parent div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I was trying to put google map on one website. But height of bad luck is that div height belongs to parent elements height.

so as div is resized google map is not loading properly.
 neither controls like zoom in side is loading properly.

**URL removed of website as issue is solved.**

code is

```
var map;
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
jQuery("#g-map").height(jQuery("#contact-info").outerHeight()); 
})

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(28.0034095,-82.5970357);
      var mapProp = {
        center:myCenter,
        zoom:9,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      setTimeout(function(){ 
 map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("g-map"),mapProp);
      var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter,
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
       }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: not sure if this may cause a problem but your map is inside an `li` that has no parent `ul` (invalid html)

Comment: if I do not call jquery height then it loads very fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved ownself

what mistake I did that for google map url should have query string to use version 3

from this url

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js&sensor=false
```

updated to

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false
```

may be it will help others. :)